# Unable to connect to mapped docker container port on the host

Tags: docker, iptables

I have docker containers defined in a docker-compose file and started using docker-compose with mapped ports.

The host has two network interface with different ip.

`interface-1 -> connects to the internet`

`interface-2 -> Connect to the LAN`

I'm able to connect to the docker container via interface-1 but it fails with  when I try to use the interface-2:

Trying to connect using `curl 10.0.0.4:8222` trigger the following

> Failed to connect to 10.0.0.4 port 8222: Network is unreachable

Issuing `netstat -tulpn` shows the host is listening on the mapped ports

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State         PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::13306                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8989                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8222                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

`docker-compose ps` shows:

```
hmis /entrypoint supervisord   Up           443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8222->80/tcp, 9000/tcp            
webdev_mysql_1        /entrypoint supervisord   Up             0.0.0.0:13306->3306/tcp, 443/tcp, 80/tcp, 9000/tcp 
webdev_phpmyadmin_1   /run.sh supervisord -n    Up           0.0.0.0:8989->80/tcp, 9000/tcp
```

The following is the iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)

target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)

target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)

target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

The routing table output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         199.111.62.9    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-f03404013814
199.211.62.8    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eno1
```

Comment: can you show  routing table on the server ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan routing table added

Comment: what is ip address of client in LAN  ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Client ip is 10.0.0.4